# Windows 8, WinJS, and unload event. What should be unloaded?

Tags: javascript, windows-8

I'm building a Windows 8 app, and I have an empty unload event handler on each page view. I'm just wondering what should be unloaded?

I'm assuming Listviews, attachedEventListeners, etc.? But, looking through the documentation, I can't find any resource that defines what should actually be unloaded.

Comment: Some info on event listeners particularly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535251/avoiding-memory-leaks-winjs-eventlisteners

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you probably do not need to manually unload anything. It is javascript after all, that is what garbage collection is for.

This event will most likely be used for other logic that you want to run when the page is unloaded.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I knew that JavaScript would take care of that eventually, but thought there might be something special that MS was expecting there.